# Change in one column should make change in other column too

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have two columns lets say A and B:

```
A     B
A12   A14
A13   A22
B54   A43
B43   B52
A43   B52
A43   B53
```

and so on.

When I try to change A, the entries in B remain the same, they don't change according to A. 
When I try to arrange A depending on their occurrence, B doesn't follow the same thing. It remains in the same position.
Here is the output I'm getting:

```
     A     B
   A43   A14
   A43   A22
   A12   A43
   A13   B52
   B54   B52 #no change occurs
   B43   B53 #no change occurs
```

Expected output will be something like:

```
     A     B
    A43   B52   #Change in A should make change in B as well. 
    A43   B53   #values in B should get affected due to changes in A
    A12   A14
    A13   A22
    B54   A43
    B43   B52
```

Since A43 is repeated twice, it should be first. 
I'm using this code but the change is applied only to A and not to B.

```
import pandas as pd
y= M['A']= M['A'].astype(str)
i= M['B']= M['B'].astype(str)
e= y[y!='nan']
z= i[i!= 'nan']
f= (list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, c) for i,c in Counter(e).most_common())))
j= [''.join(x) for x in zip(e, z)]
print(f)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please try to explain the logic of what you're trying to do instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I selected A and B, removed 'nan' values and then arranged A with most repeating value at the top. I zipped A with B so that it'll change as the A is changing. I even tried rearranging values after zipping but it still gives me the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify the second column, you need at some point to get the index of the line that has to be modified. I don't really know pandas library but, I can give you a solution :

```
import pandas as pd
import collections

M = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A12', 'A13', 'B54', 'B43', 'A43', 'A43'], 'B': ['A14', 'A22', 'A43', 'B52', 'B52', 'B53']}

output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])

for i, c in collections.Counter(e).most_common():
    lines = M.loc[M['A']==i].index.values   # returns line indices
    for line in lines:
        output.loc[len(output)] = M.iloc[line]
```

And the result is:

```
In [74]: output
Out[74]:
     A    B
0  A43  B52
1  A43  B53
2  A12  A14
3  A13  A22
4  B54  A43
5  B43  B52
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! And it worked for me. Thanks a lot.